# Install4J "corrupted java VM"

Tags: install4j

I have a customer who is experiencing problems installing our Java app on 64 bit Windows. We test in that environment and can't reproduce the issue.

He's getting a message saying the JVM is corrupted then he's offered the chance to locate one. This is odd because we package the JVM with the installer & have never seen this issue anywhere else.

[image: First error dialog]
[image: Install4J offers to locate a JVM]

Any ideas?

Comment: Ask the customer to start the installer with the command line parameter /create-i4j-log and send you the log, it will contain information about the JVM search sequence and possibly why it fails for the bundled JRE.

Comment: Did you figure this issue out? One of my customers is seeing this as well and I cannot repro. Also, Ingo, I tried running the installer with the argument you mentioned, but it doesn't create any log files. From the Install4J manual I understand that its supposed to tell me about the location of the log file, but thats not happening. I am simply running it like this - C:\Users\Name\Desktop>InstallerName.exe /create-i4j-log